# How to give output location of file in shell script?

Tags: r, shell, perl, variables

I have a a Shell script that contain a Perl script and R script.

my Shell script R.sh:-

```
#!/bin/bash
./R.pl                               #calling Perl script
`perl -lane 'print $F[0]' /media/data/abc.cnv > /media/data/abc1.txt`;
                                     #Shell script
 Rscript R.r                         #calling R script
```

This is my R.pl (head):-

```
`export path=$PATH:/media/exe_folder/bin`;
print "Enter the path to your input file:";
$base_dir ="/media/exe_folder";
chomp($CEL_dir = <STDIN>);
opendir (DIR, "$CEL_dir") or die "Couldn't open directory $CEL_dir";
$cel_files = "$CEL_dir"."/cel_files.txt";
open(CEL,">$cel_files")|| die "cannot open $file to write";
print CEL "cel_files\n";
for ( grep { /^[\w\d]/ } readdir DIR ){

print CEL "$CEL_dir"."/$_\n";
}close (CEL);
```

The output of Perl script is input for Shell script and Shell's output is input for R script.

I want to run the Shell script by providing the input file name and output file name like :-

```
./R.sh  home/folder/inputfile.txt  home/folder2/output.txt
```

If  folder contain many files then it will take only user define file and process it.
Is There is a way to do this?

Comment: You could pass the file names either as parameter to the script, or via environment variables.

Comment: Do you mean `perl perl_script.pl <parameters for perl> ¦ sh shell_script.sh <parameters for shell> ¦ r r_script.r <parameters for r script>` and you want to put that command line into another shell script? (assuming that perl & shell script write to `stdout` and that shell & R script read from `stdin`)

Comment: @StefanBecker I want to pass parameter one time only for shell script.   ./R.sh <path and of input file>  < path amd name of output file> .  R.sh is  first  calling one Perl script and then one R script.

Comment: Please provide [mcve], in your case at least the contents of `R.sh`

Comment: @StefanBecker see edits

Comment: What do you mean by _output of Perl script_ - the standard output (which would be just the prompt), or the files `cel_files.txt` and `temp.txt` (which contain only a list of pathnames, wherefore a Perl script is overkill)? Neither is used by your code as _input for Shell script_, so you didn't post the real scripts.

Comment: @Armali This is only the head part of R.pl

Comment: If you show only a part of the script, you shall show the relevant part. Again, what is the _output of Perl script_? What has the directory name prompted for by the Perl script have to do with the _input file name_ you want to give? Where does the _output file name_ come into play? What are `/media/data/abc.cnv` and `/media/data/abc1.txt` with respect to this all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# command line parameters
_input_file=$1
_output_file=$2

# @TODO: not sure if this path is the one you intended...
_script_path=$(dirname $0)

# sanity checks
if [[ -z "${_input_file}"  ]] ||
   [[ -z "${_output_file}" ]]; then
    echo 1>&2 "usage: $0 <input file> <output file>"
    exit 1
fi
if [[ ! -r "${_input_file}" ]]; then
    echo 1>&2 "ERROR: can't find input file '${input_file}'!"
    exit 1
 fi

 # process input file
 # 1. with Perl script (writes to STDOUT)
 # 2. post-process with Perl filter
 # 3. run R script (reads from STDIN, writes to STDOUT)
 perl ${_script_path}/R.pl <"${_input_file}"      | \
     perl -lane 'print $F[0]'                     | \
     Rscript ${_script_path}/R.r >"${_output_file}"

 exit 0
```

Please see the notes how the called scripts should behave.

**NOTE:** I don't quite understand why you need to post-process the output of the Perl script with Perl filter. Why not integrate it directly into the Perl script itself?

---

**BONUS CODE:** this is how you would write the main loop in `R.pl` to act as proper filter, i.e. reading lines from `STDIN` and writing the result to `STDOUT`. You can use the same approach also in other languages, e.g. R.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# read lines from STDIN
while (<STDIN>) {
    chomp;

    # add your processing code here that does something with $_, i.e. the line
    # EXAMPLE: upper case first letter in all words on the line
    s/\b([[:lower:]])/\U\1/;

    # write result to STDOUT
    print "$_\n";
}
```

Comment: Please see edits : My code take the path of file Now I want to modifies it what changes are required in Perl script.

Comment: It is a bad idea to hard-code file paths in scripts. Instead either read/write to STDIN/STDOUT or accept the file names as command line parameters. I think this is the root cause of your problem.