# How to introduce a Shell input file as Perl input file

Tags: shell, perl

I'm having some troubles trying to insert a bash variable inside my Perl code. 
In Shell script :-

```
_input_file     # contain input file name
_output_file    # contain output folder name
```

How to introduce input file and output file to Perl script. So Perl script can read that input file.

Comment: You can also just pass them as arguments to the script. Or are you trying specifically to access the shell environment variables?

Comment: I have 3 scripts and I am calling all in a shell script  so I specified input and output file in shell script so I can call them in all script. But I don't know how to introduce these variable to other script.

Comment: you can also use Getopt::Long https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start your Perl script with this:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input_file = $ARGV[0]
   or die "usage: $0 <input file> <output file>\n";
my $output_file = $ARGV[1]
   or die "usage: $0 <input file> <output file>\n";
```

... and then you can call it like this from shell script

```sh
"${_script_path}/my_perl.pl" "${_input_file}" "${_output_file}"
```

---

**NOTE:** if you have only one input file and one output file, then you should consider writing a filter instead, i.e. reading from STDIN and writing to STDOUT. Then you can integrate into a pipe like this

```sh
[command that generates input] | perl my_perl.pl | [command that consumes output]
```

Comment: I strongly recommend quoting the variables, as in `perl myscript "$_input_file" "$_output_file"`. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cp_.24file_.24target.

Comment: Sorry, developer asleep at the keyboard.

Comment: I guess I only write filters or use [Getopt::Long](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long) in my code :-)

Comment: A common arrangement is to accept a *list* of input files, and simply produce output on standard output. That way your program behaves as expected in a shell pipeline.

Comment: These are all valid comments, but I'll refer to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54572433/how-to-give-output-location-of-file-in-shell-script/) that preceded this one.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever possible, I would recommend writing programs as Unix filters - that is, read from `STDIN` and write to `STDOUT`. This makes your programs as flexible as possible and is usually easier to write (as you avoid all that tedious opening of files).

In Perl, you can use `<>` to read from `STDIN` and `print()` to write to `STDOUT`. So one common approach would look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# While there is data available on STDIN
# Read a line and store it in $_
while (<>) {
  # Do something useful with the data in $_
  ...
  # Print $_ to STDOUT
  print;
}
```

Then you just need to ensure that STDIN and STDOUT are connected to the correct files when you call your program. If `_input_file` and `_output_file` are environment variables and your program is called `my_filter`, then you could call it like this:

```
my_filter < "$_input_file" > "$_output_file"
```

Comment: "# While there is data available on STDIN" :-)

Comment: @JRFerguson Oops. Thanks, fixed :-/